# Update Text property for all entities in Datastore Google App Engine with GQL

Tags: sql, json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I need to update all the entities in Datastore that meet certain criteria, but the property I want to modify is Text Type and it already has a JSON value, like this:

Property Name: default_values
Type: String
Value: {"text1":"", "path1":"",  "text2": "", "path2": ""}

And I need to update the Value with something like this:

Value: {"text1":"", "path1":"", "image1":"",  "text2": "", "path2": "", "image2": ""}

How can I do the UPDATE in Google Query Language for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Datastore's GQL does not support update statements.  You'll need to read, modify, & write each entity. If you have a lot of entities, you should look into using Cloud Dataflow for processing all the entities.